# ASP.NET Dynamic data Change text field to dropdown and populate with some data

Tags: drop-down-menu, asp.net-3.5, dynamic-data

I have an ASP.NET dynamic data site and for one of the text fields within Edit and Insert templates  I'd like to covert it to dropdown and populate that drop down programmatically. Can you help or point into right direction ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you will need to do is create a Custom FieldTemplate and use the UIHint Attribute on the column/property to direct ASP.NET Dynamic Data to use that Custom FieldTemplate in Insert and Edit mode.

see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute.aspx

and here: http://www.asp.net/learn/3.5-SP1/

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at these samples on my blog:
[The Anatomy of a FieldTemplate.](http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2008/07/dynamic-data-and-field-templates.html) 
[Your First FieldTemplate.](http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2008/07/dynamic-data-and-field-templates-your.html) 
[An Advanced FieldTemplate.](http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2008/07/dynamic-data-and-field-templates_28.html) 
[A Second Advanced FieldTemplate.](http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2008/08/dynamic-data-and-field-templates-second.html)

Answer (score -2):

There is a easier way to do that, by simply creating in a partial class separated from the code generated by EF, with the atribute:

```
[DisplayColumn("columnName")]
public partial class Product{}
```

Hope it will be helpful for future references.

Comment: This is not the answer which asked.